# optionbuilder.IsConfigured always false on abstract dbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a dbContext for readonly operations and a dbContext for write operations, targeting the same database tables.
I tried to make an abstract dbContext that the two other contexts inherit from, in order not to have to copy the database configurations twice.

I Inject my contexts in program.cs like this :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WriteContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));;
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ReadOnlyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ReadOnlyConnectionString")));
```

Both contexts look like this:

```
 public partial class ReadOnlyContext : AbstractContext
{
    public ReadOnlyContext()
    {
    }

    public ReadOnlyContext(DbContextOptions<AbstractContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

}
```

my AbstractContext looks like this :

```
public abstract partial class AbstractContext : DbContext
{


    public AbstractContext()
    {
    }

    public AbstractContext(DbContextOptions<AbstractContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    // DbSet declarations 

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
           // string connexion for reproducing the problem
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=devServer;Database=myDb;Integrated Security=true;Application Name=API Suivi Support;Connect Timeout=30;");
        }
    }
    // db configuration
}
```

When I run the application, condition !optionsBuilder.IsConfigured in the abstract class always returns true and my dev connection string is used.

If I make the two distinct contexts without the abstract class and copying the configuration in both, everything works fine.

How should I do to be able to instantiate each context with the abstract class and their own connection string?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking.  Can you add a short, complete repro of the unexpected behavior you are seeing?

Comment: You can put the connection string in your app.config/web.config under `<connectionStrings>` then pass the connection string setting Name instead of the connection string literal. This way you can use config transforms between development and testing / production environments.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `UseSqlServer` in `builder.Services.AddDbContext<WriteContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));` causes IsConfigured to be true when `OnConfiguring` runs.

you can see this in the [Source of DbContextOptionsBuilder](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/f72888f3ae390e38f4a6ca4ad1acc8f0659e2661/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Infrastructure/Internal/SqlServerOptionsExtension.cs#L80-L81)

```
public virtual bool IsConfigured => _options.Extensions.Any(e => e.Info.IsDatabaseProvider);
```

and the [Source of SqlServerOptionsExtension](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/f72888f3ae390e38f4a6ca4ad1acc8f0659e2661/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Infrastructure/Internal/SqlServerOptionsExtension.cs#L80-L81) (which is the extension added by the `UseSqlServer` call.

```
public override bool IsDatabaseProvider => true;
```

Basically the `IsConfigured` property is there to let you know someone already called a `UseSqlServer` or equivalent.

Addendum:
To clarify, the issue the OP has is caused because he is preconfiguring the context, it has nothing to do with having a abstract base class.
I do not know if the abstract base class will cause any other issues with EF.

Comment: Hello... by calling `builder.Services.AddDbContext<WriteContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")))` in my case, `IsConfigured` is still false.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use DI when you are calling the context, if you need it in any service class for exemple, don't create new instance with the new keyword, instead inject the context in the service constructor.

and the framework will call configure it with the correct connection string.

that's when the

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
{
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```